# Disable home key for specific activity in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to disable home key for specific activity in app, as I tried
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`
 to set as DEFAULT LAUNCHER but here through out all activity the home key will be set as default launcher instead of this I need to disable home key for a specific activity only. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what do you mean by `home key`

Comment: You cannot and should not attempt to disable a user's home key. The home key is JUST that, the user's home away from applications. Removing this would lock the user into your app and can't leave. VERY UNDESIRABLE behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solution for this.
Create custom class

```
private static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        params.dimAmount = 0.0F; // transparent
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 0xffffff);
        setOwnerActivity(activity);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
        return true;
    }

    protected final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0);
        setContentView(framelayout);
    }
}
```

Then two utiles methods for lock and unlock.

```
private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;

public void lock(Activity activity) {
    if (mOverlayDialog == null) {
        mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
        mOverlayDialog.show();
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
        mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
        mOverlayDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Behaviorally speaking an application cannot overlay the navigation bar without very high level permissions that a 3p app will never be granted. Your approach will not block the navigation bar interactions. It will however block touch going to lockscreen screen though, but hitting the home button will cause the activity to go away.